# How to install only a subset of the packages listed in a packagegroup?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I have written the following packagegroup called `packagegroup-amatek.bb` for testing purposes :

```
# Copyright (C) 2012-2013 Freescale Semiconductor
# Released under the MIT license (see COPYING.MIT for the terms)

DESCRIPTION = "Example package group"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COREBASE}/LICENSE;md5=3f40d7994397109285ec7b81fdeb3b58 \
                    file://${COREBASE}/meta/COPYING.MIT;md5=3da9cfbcb788c80a0384361b4de20420"

PR = "r5"

inherit packagegroup

PROVIDES = "${PACKAGES}"
PACKAGES += " \
    ${PN}-package1 \
    ${PN}-package2 \
"


RDEPENDS_${PN}-package1 = " \
   package1-depend1 \
"

RDEPENDS_${PN}-package2 = " \
   package2-depend2 \
"


PACKAGE_ARCH = "${MACHINE_ARCH}"
```

If in my custom image file (`amatek-image`) I include only `packagegroup-amatek-package1`:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL = "packagegroup-amatek-package1"
```

I would expect that `package2-depend2` is not installed because it is a dependency of the package `packagegroup-amatek-package2` which is not installed.

However, `bitbake amatek-image -g -u depexp` shows that `package2-depend2` is installed as well:

[image]

Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

The dependency explorer will show what is built, not what is installed. If you build the above image, you will find that only packagegroup-amatek-package1 is installed as you'd expect. There is a difference between what the system has to build and what is installed at runtime. It has to build packagegroup-amatek-package2 since its part of the same recipe as packagegroup-amatek-package1 and the system doesn't partially build recipes, it either does or does not.