# Remove packagegroup from image but keep one package of it which is an empty package

Tags: image, package, yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

Hi all,

I am new to Yocto and the BitBake eco system and currently facing an issue when trying to remove a packagegroup BUT at the same time KEEP one of its packages - which is an empty package.

It goes like this: When building my image, the `packagegroup-core-buildessential` ([that can be found here](https://github.com/yoctoproject/poky/blob/master/meta/recipes-core/packagegroups/packagegroup-core-buildessential.bb)) is added to the final image. Most of the packages it contains, are NOT required in my final image --> therefor I wish to remove it. As a first attempt, what I did was to remove the entire `packagegroup-core-buildessential` from the final image by applying the following:

`IMAGE_INSTALL_remove += "packagegroup-core-buildessential"`

When doing this the entire `packagegroup-core-buildessential` was removed, but then I found out that another recipe in my image `python3-pycparser_2.21.bb` is `RDEPENDS` on one of the packages from `packagegroup-core-buildessential` which happens to be also an "empty package". This is the `cpp-symlinks` package.

As another attempt what I tried to do was to manually add the `cpp-symlinks` to the final image by doing `IMAGE_INSTALL += "cpp-symlinks"` and also remove the entire `packagegroup-core-buildessential` as before --> this also did not work. It provided the error:

> Error:
> Problem 1: conflicting requests
> nothing provides cpp-symlinks needed by packagegroup-core-buildessential-1.0-r0.noarch
>
> Problem 2:
> package python3-cffi-1.12.3-r0.corei7_64 requires python3-pycparser, but none of the providers can be installed conflicting requests
>
> nothing provides cpp-symlinks needed by python3-pycparser-2.19-r0.corei7_64

I went over the following Q&A:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680665/remove-packagegroup-from-image), [this one as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57623639/removing-a-sub-package-from-a-main-package-in-yocto?rq=3), [this one also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272212/how-to-install-only-a-subset-of-the-packages-listed-in-a-packagegroup?rq=3) and [eventually this one which seems the closests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61372769/do-not-understand-error-with-packagegroup) - but still not sure what I should do.

Additional and final attempt was to "override" the values of the `RDEPENDS:packagegroup-core-buildessential` within a dedicated packagegroup-core-buildessential.bbappend file (i.e. - in my case I only kept the `cpp` and `cpp-symlinks` packages). This caused the problem above to raise again.

What (mainly, I guess) distinguish the situation I'm facing Vs. the one described in the last link, is that there is no `cpp-symlinks.bb` file (or anything "similar").

So the questions are:

1. What exactly is an "empty package"?
2. How can I resolve the issue I'm facing (trying to remove the `packagegroup-core-buildessential` BUT at the same time "keep" the `cpp-symlinks`?

Answer (score 0):

After searching some more on the network, what I found out is that in order to eliminate the error raised (for my last attempt), I need to add the [ALLOW_EMPTY](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-ALLOW_EMPTY) settings for the `cpp-symlink` package which is an "empty" package (i.e. - it does not get any files to be installed on the final image). This setting was added to the `local.conf`.

BitBake by defualt, will remove (not install) any empty package. In order to let him know that "it is fine that `cpp-symlink` will be installed even if it is empty" what was added is:

`ALLOW_EMPTY_cpp-symlink = "1"` (to the `local.conf` file). Also, as a reminder, I have added a `packagegroup-core-buildessential.bbappend` file for the relevant packagegroup.